# Split large file(s) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, symfony, process, split

I have a Laravel app that allows for uploading of large files. Once there have completed the upload, I'd like to have a process run on the server side that uses the Linux split command to split the file into smaller pieces.

I'm using the builtin Process command that is already present in Laravel. Here is the code that has me stumped.

```
    $command = ('split -n10 -d file.mkv mySubFile_  /var/www/storage/app/public/workinprogress/');
    $process = new Process($command);
    $process->run();

    // executes after the command finishes
    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }

    return $process->getOutput();
```

When I run it, I receive the following code:

> split: extra operand '/var/www/storage/app/public/workinprogress/'

I'm so close on this one, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just remove the extra param, so it becomes `split -n10 -d file.mkv mySubFile_`

Comment: That does work, however it needs to run in that dir because that's where the file is. If I take out the path, it runs at the root of the application.

Comment: the path should be prepend to the file like this `split -n10 -d file.mkv /destination/path/mySubFile_`

Comment: Thanks xmhafix, that did it.